# adding fields and labels in backend

Tags: catalog, product-attribute, custom-attributes

I have the following code in my sql setup trying to add an integer value in my backend as a custom attribute:

```
$productAttributesSetup->addAttribute('catalog_product', 'calculator_product_id', 
    array(
        'backend'         => '',
        'type'            => 'int',
        'frontend'        => '',
        'input'           => 'text',
        'label'           => 'Calculator',
        'frontend_class'  => '',
        'source'          => '',
        'required'        => false,
        'user_defined'    => true,
        'default'         => 0,
        'unique'          => 0,
        'note'            => '',
        'global'          => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_WEBSITE
    )
);
```

Im making a mistake and I dont know where. the attribute display the "label: Calculator" in catalog-product backend but not the field to edit the value. could you please shed some light of what do I have to include in order to have a text field defined in my script. brgds!

Comment: where did you add this script ? can you try one more property `'visible' => TRUE` along with other properties

Comment: I placed it on my sql folder of my module. visible refers to frontend?

Answer (score 1):

First of all delete the attribute before rerunning the install script. Then make sure to use core_setup. In your config.xml add this (or replace existing `<mymodule_setup/>`

```
        <mymodule_setup>
            <setup>
                <module>Namespace_Mymodule</module>
                <class>Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup</class>
            </setup>
            <connection>
                <use>core_setup</use>
            </connection>
        </mymodule_setup>
```

Now your code should be like this

```
$installer = $this;
/* @var $installer Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup */

$installer->startSetup();


$installer->addAttribute('catalog_product', 'calculator_product_id', array(
        'group'             => 'Prices',               //The Tab you want this attribute to appear in
        'type'              => 'int',
        'backend'           => '',
        'frontend'          => '',
        'label'             => 'Calculator',
        'input'             => '',                    //Leave this blank
        'class'             => 'validate-digits',     //you can leave this blank, but this is a good validator
        'source'            => '',
        'is_global'         => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_WEBSITE,
        'visible'           => true,
        'required'          => false,
        'user_defined'      => true,
        'default'           => '',
        'searchable'        => false,
        'filterable'        => false,
        'comparable'        => false,
        'visible_on_front'  => false,
        'unique'            => false,
        'used_in_product_listing'=> false,
        'apply_to'          => 'simple,virtual,downloadable',  //bundle ... or whatever you like

    ));


$installer->endSetup();
```

Comment: interesting, which field is the one defining the input area added into the backend? thanks!

Comment: @s_h 'input'             => '', is the one that does the trick. Actually you can omit it altogether I think. I don't quite get why myself, but I recon type 'int' is quite special for Varien folks.

Comment: I made those changes but it didnt work.

Comment: Did you delete the existing attribute and change the midule version to rerun setup? Is this a vanilla Magento installation?

Comment: I made those changes and now attribute is displayed in manage attributes but no information (label or field ) appear inside prices of catalog-product. weird

Comment: Wait a min, you're saying that up to now it was not displayed in the attributes list? Anyway.

Is the type of the product you are looking in the 'apply_to' array (for example 'simple')?

Is the new attribute assigned to the "attribute set" of the product you are looking?

Is your magento installation in English? (Because magento names the tabs in the installation language not explicitly english.)

Comment: sorry. yes it was displayed on attributes, and in attributes set. but right now is not displaying anything on catalog product. no label and no field. brgds

Comment: this is the html information that I have right now:

Comment: <tr>
    <td class="label"><label for="calculator_id">Calculator</label></td>
    <td class="value">
                    </td>
    <td class="scope-label"><span class="nobr">[WEBSITE]</span></td>
    </tr>

Comment: td class="value" is empty, not displaying any field to edit.